# How do i add _id column to after $group aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

If a collection called regions contains the following documents:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("6384557894421b5e9d7aa7ea"),
  region: "US",
  name: "United State",
},
{
  _id: ObjectId("6384557894421b5e9d7aa7eb"),
  region: "US",
  name: "United State",
}
```

after run below in mongosh:

```
db.regions.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: {region: "$region", name: "$name"}, priority: {$sum: 1}}},
    {$project: { code: "$_id.region", name: "$_id.name", priority: "$priority"}
])
```

the result looks like this:

```
{ "code" : "US", "name" : "United State", "priority" : 2}
```

how can i get below?

```
{ "code" : "US", "name" : "United State", "priority" : 2, _id: ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxx")}
```

add {$project: ?????} or {$addFields: ??????} after $group ?

My fault. I didn't make it clear, in fact, I want to add a column of _id of type ObjectId after $group aggregate so that I can $out to another collection.
Thanks for your prompt response, from which I feel the power and popularity of stackoverflow.
Inspired by [@Gibbs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2694184/gibbs) hint, I can roughly achieve this with:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      "id": {
        $push: "$_id"
      },
      _id: {
        region: "$region",
        name: "$name"
      },
      priority: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      code: "$_id.region",
      name: "$_id.name",
      priority: "$priority",
      _id: {
        $first: "$id"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Another question, what **if the source collection doesn't have an _id**, how can i do?

Comment: Since you have perform the group, I doubt that you can't get the result with `_id` is an ObjectId.

Comment: Do you want this https://mongoplayground.net/p/bqCVqk60M-0 ?

Comment: What would be the value of `_id` if the result document is a group of documents, each with a different `_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to add a column of _id of type ObjectId after $group aggregate so that I can $out to another collection.

Counterintuitively, you can achieve this by specifically *excluding* the `_id` field in the `$project`.

Given your two sample documents in a collection called `regions` and nothing in  a collection called `grouped`:

```
> db.regions.find()
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("6384557894421b5e9d7aa7ea"),
    region: 'US',
    name: 'United State'
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("6384557894421b5e9d7aa7eb"),
    region: 'US',
    name: 'United State'
  }
]
> db.grouped.find()

>
```

```
db.regions.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: {region: "$region", name: "$name"}, priority: {$sum: 1}}},
    {$project: { _id: 0, code: "$_id.region", name: "$_id.name", priority: "$priority"} },
    {$out: "grouped"}
])
```

The two changes are to exclude the `_id` field from the output of the aggregation (`_id: 0` in `$project`) and append the `$out`. After running the command the `grouped` collection contains this document with an automatically generated ObjectId for `_id` as requested:

```
test> db.grouped.find()
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("6384ee00b2c2480d11720d54"),
    code: 'US',
    name: 'United State',
    priority: 2
  }
]
```

##### Why this works

There are a few things happening at the same time here. The first is that if we just run the original aggregation, we see the following output:

```
> db.regions.aggregate([
   {$group: {_id: {region: "$region", name: "$name"}, priority: {$sum: 1}}},
   {$project: {  code: "$_id.region", name: "$_id.name", priority: "$priority"} }
])
[
  {
    _id: { region: 'US', name: 'United State' },
    code: 'US',
    name: 'United State',
    priority: 2
  }
]
```

Notice that there already *is* an `_id` field here. This is due to [this behavior of projection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#suppress-the-_id-field):

> By default, the `_id` field is included in the output documents. To exclude the `_id` field from the output documents, you must explicitly specify the suppression of the `_id` field in `$project`

If we manually exclude `_id` as the documentation states, the resulting document no longer includes it as expected:

```
> db.regions.aggregate([
   {$group: {_id: {region: "$region", name: "$name"}, priority: {$sum: 1}}},
   {$project: {  _id: 0, code: "$_id.region", name: "$_id.name", priority: "$priority"} }
[ 
  { 
    code: 'US', 
    name: 'United State', 
    priority: 2 
  } 
]
```

So why *is* there a a value for `_id` in the document when we `$out` it to another collection? This is due to [the behavior (as a note at the bottom of that section) of the `_id` field itself](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/#the-_id-field):

> Most MongoDB driver clients will include the `_id` field and generate an `ObjectId` before sending the insert operation to MongoDB; however, if the client sends a document without an _id field, the `mongod` will add the `_id` field and generate the `ObjectId`.

So MongoDB itself is taking care of generating the ObjectId for the `_id` field when it attempts to do the insert after the `$out`.

Comment: Very patient answer. You're right. I didn't think about it carefully.

Comment: Glad to help. If the answer solves the question, please consider accepting it to indicate to others that it has been resolved.

Comment: Feel sorry. I don't have enough reputation to vote up your answer. Wait for it to be added in the future.

Comment: I'd love an upvote in the future if you feel that the answer deserves it. But just for completeness, [there's no reputation minimum to accept an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398026/20042973)